# How to increase downloading speed of a file over internet?

Tags: vb.net, performance, download

I have an this code for download file but it's gives me slow performance rate.

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5")
client.Proxy = Nothing
client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(URL), cdirectory & ext)
```

How to split and merge one file for fast download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download a single file in multiple parts to improve performance then you will need to create an `HttpWebRequest` for each part and call its `AddRange` method to specify the range of bytes that you want that request to download.  I've never done it myself so I have no example to provide but, if I wanted to do it, the first thing I'd do is read the MSDN documentation for the `HttpWebRequest.AddRange` method and then search the web for that same method.

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode, that adds no value.  That's going to perform exactly the same way as a WebClient.  The question was how to split the download to go faster.  How does your suggestion address that?